# Балансировка идеально сбалансированного дерева

Tags: дискретная-математика, дерево

Возможно ли балансировка для идеального баланса быстрее, чем за O(n)(полное перестроение дерева)? Напомню, что бинарное дерево назовается идеально сбалансированным, если для каждой его вершины количество вершин в левом и правом поддереве различаются не более чем на 1.